# How can I get rid of emergency mode after change in fstab file?

Tags: fstab

I am using linux mint 18.3. When I connected my external hard drive to my computer, I got a "Failed to connect location" error. After doing some research, I found out that I needed to mount it and added the line

```
/dev/sdb1 /wddisk ntfs defaults,umask=1000,gid=46 0 0
```

to the fstab file. When I rebooted the system, I crashed into the Emergency Mode screen. After entering the password, I access fstab with the #sudo edit /etc/fstab command and try to return to the default mode by deleting the line I added. But I can't save the changes I made to the fstab file. I tried many commands but no result. My OS is in the /dev/sda1 directory. How can I get out of Emergency mode?

Comment: Are you sure the added line starts with a `#`?

Comment: This is a terrible title for this question as it has nearly nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: adding that line as shown would make zero difference to your system. Essentially, you've added a comment to `/etc/fstab` so, clearly, that's NOT the issue

Answer (score 2):

In emergency mode your root filesystem is usually read-only. You can check that with

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

So you need to make it read-write before trying to change the file:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I wanted to share the solution for those who have the same problem.

I entered the

```shell
nano /etc/fstab
```

command in the Emergency mode screen and deleted the line

```
/dev/sdb1 /wddisk ntfs defaults,umask=1000,gid=46 0 0
```

that I had added to the `fstab` file, saved the change in the file with the <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> keys and restarted the computer.

I found the solution to the problem from the Ubuntu Türkiye page. Contrary to the observations and suggestions of the respondents, the problem was caused by the line I added to the `fstab` file.

Comment: So your question was: "How do I save changes in a console editor?" "But I can't save the changes I made to the fstab file" is generally understood as "There is a technical problem", not as "I do not know how to make the editor save the changes."